# Setter method is not called when the text is deleted in an InputText field bounded to a property in Oracle MAF

Tags: oracle-maf

I have the following inputText field in MAF.
    < amx:inputText value="#{**bindings.searchCivilID**.inputValue}" label="civil id" id = "it1">

The setter **setSearchCivilID()** is called each time when i change the text in the field. (like - from "1" to "12").

But when I try to delete the text or totally remove the text , the setter method is not called and hence the previous value is retained in the property.

Can you guys help me out in this?

Thanks,
Haleem.

Answer (score 0):

Tick the check box:" Notify listeners when property changes" while generating generating `get() and set()` . so when the value of the field changes it will fire the method `propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("<your_variable_name>",oldValue,newValue)`